# Is it clean code?

Tags: c++, error-handling, coding-style

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class FileNotFound: public logic_error
{
public:
    explicit FileNotFound(const string& _Message):logic_error(_Message){}
};
int main()
{
    try
    {
        ifstream file;
        file.open("NoExistingFile");
        if (file.fail())
            throw FileNotFound("");
    }
    catch(const FileNotFound &e)
    {
        cout << "FileNotFound" << e.what();
    }
    catch(const exception &e)
    {
        cout << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output: FileNotFound

Is it Clean code (Robert Martin)?
std::exception not provide "location of an error".
Clean Code A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (Robert Martin) -> Chapter 7: Error Handling -> Provide Context with Exceptions

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Clean in what respect?

Comment: Were you expecting something to come out of the `what()`?

Comment: You might want to quote the relevant point from the book. I don't have my copy at hand.

Comment: Clean Code A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (Robert Martin).

Comment: It is also semi rude, because you have an if statement, that is "upper abstraction" but the two lines prior are "lower abstractions". You are declaring a file, in your main, then you attempt to open it, both "leaf" operations, or .. side effects? 
Then you have a branching that depends on an "upper abstraction" a return method of some kind that resolves a bool, so the logic here is abstracted away, and depending on the return of said bool, you actually manually throw an exception? 

right in the main method.

The entire thing should have been abstracted out into a behaviour of it's own.

Comment: Like "OpenSafely" or something like that, where an error doesn't cause the program to stop functioning, but logs the relevant error and continues.

Also because the code is located directly in main, you can't really unit test it, because it is the equivalent of simply running the entire code, meaning the code isn't composable at all. 
You should likely have made an abstract class, (functioning an interface) that would enable you to unit test this much easier, and compose your "OpenSafely" method into other parts of the code, think Dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the quoted paragraph, it is certainly not clean, because you just get the information of what happened, but you do not get the information from where the exception was thrown, therefore you can not trace it back for debugging.

Instead of using standard exceptions, I would advise to use [boost exceptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html), since they can provide the context from where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The more fundamental question is: Why use an exception in the first place? If it's a non-exceptional behavior (if it can be expected that a file might not be present), than no exception should be thrown at all. Instead control should flow along an "official path".

Answer (score 0):

*Add-on:* It is not clean in the sense of the quoted book section (because the context needed to locate the problem is not provided with the exception -as others have mentioned) but also because:

1. The custom exception is used to manipulate control flow.

So instead of :

> ```
>    throw FileNotFound("");
>  }
>  catch(const FileNotFound &e)
>  {
> ```

Do only:

```
    cout << "FileNotFound" << e.what();
```

2. The variable name 'e' is not really self explanatory and should also not be repeated.
3. The exception class should have its own file.
4. You should not use error and exception interchangably (in your question).  This is an extra tipp imho.